# get attribute value returns undefined and set value to attribute creates new attribute with value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery 1.7.1

Getting attribute value

Please refer the below outer HTML element

```
$element.get(0).outerHTML


<?xml:namespace prefix = "v" ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" />
<v:shape id=container_vml_CrosshairVertical style="HEIGHT: 1000px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px; VISIBILITY: visible; WIDTH: 1000px" coordsize = "1000,1000" fillcolor = "white" strokecolor = "black" strokeweight = "1pt" path = " m342,58 l342,374 e"></v:shape>
```

when am getting the attribute value by using following code, it returns undefined value even though it has some value.

`$element.attr('path')` -> returns `undefined`

Setting new value to existing attribute

Please refer below code setting value to attribute

```
var val= '"m 386 58 l 386 374';

$element.attr('path',val);
```

it creates new attribute with specified value instead of replacement. Please refer below outerHTML

```
<?xml:namespace prefix = "v" ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" />
<v:shape id=container_vml_CrosshairVertical style="HEIGHT: 1000px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px; VISIBILITY: visible; WIDTH: 1000px" path="m 386 58 l 386 374" coordsize = "1000,1000" fillcolor = "white" strokecolor = "black" strokeweight = "1pt" path = " m384,58 l384,374 e"></v:shape>
```

Please look the above outerHTML element it contains two path attributes. i dont know why it creates again new attribute ?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: You can't have two attributes with the same name in one element.

Comment: @Barmar yes thats what am asking it creates new attribute with value.instead of replacement

Comment: Myabe it's because of this spaces in declaration path = "?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$element.prop('path',val);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found better solution using javascript setAttribute

```
element.setAttribute('path', val);
```

this will work in all kind of cases.

Thanks,

Siva